# python error "typeerror: nonetype object not callable"

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm trying to make a simple timer script in python. I see a lot of other people have had this error too, but I think my error may be different because I'm new to python:

```
time=60
from time import sleep
while (time>0):
    print ("you have") (time) ("seconds left")
    time-=1
    sleep(1)
```

below is the result:

`>>>
 you have
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "H:\counter.py", line 4, in <module>
      print ("you have") (time) ("seconds left")
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Can anyone spot this error?
using %s has also failed me along with using +'s and str() around the time variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function can have only a single set of arguments.

```
print_statement = "you have" + str(time) + "seconds left"
print(print_statement)
```

The above code should work.

Comment: @dioretsa: Please accept my answer if it had helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong syntax for the `print` function. Please note that `print` in [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3) is a callable. So when you call it, you can pass all that you need to be printed as parameters.

Hence

```
print ("you have", time, "seconds left")
```

is the correct syntax. You can optionally also specify a separator.

---

For posterity, `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` is an error thrown when you try to use an `NoneType` **object** as a **callable**. Python flagged out when it discovered that you had tried to pass `time` (an *object*) to `print ("you have")` which returns a `NoneType` *object*.

Remember, in [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3) `print` is a **callable** and it essentially returns a `NullType` **object** (which is nothing at all for that matter, and hence **not callable**).

Comment: Even for python2, the syntax is wrong and should be `print ("you have"), (time), ("seconds left")`.  dioretsa's print almost looks like haskell function calls

Comment: @Lærne True that. :D. It is also an excellent example of tuple packing and unpacking in [tag:python-2] `print`. I only wrote in reference to [tag:python-3] because that's what the original code language looked like to me. [tag:python-2] `print` doesn't really require individual parameters to be put inside parentheses (seems excessive and promotes bad practices).