# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable (Beginner) Python

Tags: python, typeerror

It tells me there is an AssertionError in line 11.I'm new to programming, not sure if this helps.The code is supposed to give me the i-th element of the x-th row, so for row3(3) = 9 for row4(10) = 40.

```
def multiplicationtable(x):

    def row(i):
        print (x * i)
    return row

row3 = multiplicationtable(3)

assert row3(3) == 9
```

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

10 row3 = multiplicationtable(3)

---> 11 assert row3(3) == 9

AssertionError:

Comment: `multiplicationtable` doesn't return anything. Maybe you meant to return `row`?

Comment: It helps a lot to give a more complete error message. (Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239023/python-error-typeerror-nonetype-object-not-callable) for a good example of showing the error message.)

Comment: Oh yeah you are right, thanks. But now i get an AssertionError instead.

Comment: It is unclear what you expect your code to do, and how to produce an AssertionError from code which doesn't call `assert`.  See if you could [edit] this into a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `AssertionError` because `row(i)` function is not returning any value. It should be written in this way:

```
def multiplicationtable(x):

    def row(i):
        print (x * i)
        return x * i
    return row
row3 = multiplicationtable(3)

assert row3(3) == 9
```